# Tips for working with Pre-1000 A.D. Dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm curious if anyone has any good solutions for accurately building dates prior to the year 1000 A.D. - particularly the years 1 - 100 AD.

For example, if I want to build a date for the start of the 1st millenium, I can't just do...

```
new Date(Date.UTC(1,0,1,0,0,0,0));
```

because it tries to be "smart" and assume that 1 is 1901, which gives me...

```
Sun Dec 31 1900 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

The same thing goes for the year 99...

```
new Date(Date.UTC(99,0,1,0,0,0,0));
```

which becomes

```
Thu Dec 31 1998 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I love this. Kind of an anti-Y2K bug. This is precisely what happens when things are poorly written and then hacked around after-the-fact.

Comment: Are you using `getFullYear()` instead of `year` because of some issue with time zone inconsistencies that would appear? Maybe if the month was -1 for example it could end up changing the year? Just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the basic solution I came up with. If a date is prior to year 1000, I just add a 1000 to it while constructing the date, then use `setUTCFullYear()` afterwards.

```
if (year >= 0 && year < 1000) { 
  var d = new Date(Date.UTC(year + 1000,mon,day,hour,min,sec,0));
  d.setUTCFullYear(d.getFullYear() - 1000); 
  return d; 
}
```

1000 may be overkill since I was only having problems with pre-100 dates... but, whatever.

Comment: I ***like*** it when people post & accept their own answer. They don't need to - their problem is solved. But doing so will help others who read the question in future. If it helped ***you***, then please upvote

Comment: It's actually better to add 1200 instead of 1000 in order to simulate the leap-year-ness of the original year. The leap year cycle repeats every 400 years (it's more complicated than just 4 years) and 1200 is the first multiple of 400 that is over 1000.

Answer (score 6):

i prefer:

```
var d = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, min, sec, 0));
d.setUTCFullYear(year);
```

this always works for all supported year values.

the setUTCFullYear() call fixes JavaScript's intentional *bug* if you ask me.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the [setUTC... functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) on a date object after its creation?

```
setUTCDate()
setUTCFullYear()
setUTCMonth()
setUTCHours()
setUTCMinutes()
setUTCSeconds()
```

Comment: I needed to convert an SAP date string ("yyyymmdd") into a JavaScript date. SAP uses dates ranging from 0001/01/01 up to 9999/12/31. I parsed year, month and date into single strings, initialized a default date `var date = new Date(0);` and used the `.setUTC...()` setters. Don't forget that months are 0-based (January = 0).

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the year again, like [setFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) or [setUTCFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
The Date can store 285 616 years before and after 1. 1. 1970.

```
var d = new Date( 0000, 1, 29 );       // Thu Mar 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT+0100
d.setFullYear(-0004);                  // Wed Mar 01 -0004 00:00:00 GMT+0057
d.setFullYear( 0000, 1, 29 );          // Tue Feb 29 0000 00:00:00 GMT+0057
                                       // Yes, year zero was a leap year
```

Explanation:

1. new Date( year [4-digit number, 0–99 map to 1900–1999], month [0-11], day [def. 1], hours, minutes, seconds, milisecs ); is same like Date.UTC but in local timezone.
2. hours, minutes and seconds will be automatically filled with zeros.
3. the year lower than 1900 is converted to 1900 by default.
4. the year 1900 is not a leap year, so it is shifted to next closest day 1. Mar.
5. so, we have to set the year to zero 0000 again (year always must be min. 4-digit in this case), month and day. We use setFullYear() method with optional parameters for month and day; then if the year will be a leap year, it won’t be shifted.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what `Date.UTC` and the `Date` constructor function (called with numbers as arguments) [are supposed to do](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.9.4). A simple workaround is to use `Date.parse`, which will not apply any corrections

```
new Date(Date.parse('0001-01-04'));
new Date(Date.parse('0001-01-04T18:00:00Z'));
```

Comment: I understand that the constructors were working as designed. My question was how to get around it. `Date.parse()` is an interesting solution - thanks.

Comment: The use of *Date.parse* is redundant. `new Date('0001-01-04')` must produce an identical result per [*ECMA-262*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date), as the string must be parsed identically in both cases (it's been that way since Ed 3 in 1999). Any other result would be somewhat less than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make some arbitrary date `d` and call `d.setUTCFullYear(myDate)`.  This seems to be working for me in Chrome's console.

Comment: this solution would only set the correct year value while the other time components would be 'arbitrary'. *grin* But seriously, in the spirit of your answer, by what i'm sure you mean, i agree this is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided hints at a fix. The javascript date object was copied from Java, so has all its bugs too. There is not much point to [Gregorian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) dates before 1582 anyway since before that various other calendars were in use.

Comment: wow, i was totally unaware that Java's date object auto subtracts 1900. yikes! the point to Gregorian dates before 1582 is why there's even a name for such a thing: a 'proleptic' calendar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar