# How can I create a JavaScript Date representing January 1st 0001?

Tags: javascript

### NOTE: This is *not* a duplicate. I already refer to the other question mentioned. I'm pointing out that the advice given there doesn't work.

I'm trying to create a JavaScript date representing the January 1st 0001 (i.e. the start of year 1 AD).

At first I naively thought that this would do it:

```
const date = new Date(1, 0, 1);
```

...but that doesn't work. That actually yields January 1st 1901.

This behaviour (which is [documented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5863327/98422)) is discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5863327/98422).

The proposed solution is to construct the date and then use `setUTCFullYear` to set the actual year required, like this:

```
const date = new Date(1, 0, 1);
date.setUTCFullYear(1);
```

Well, I tried doing that, and the date I end up with is:

> Sun Dec 31 0000 23:58:45 GMT-0001 (Greenwich Mean Time)

See [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qwgbqv) for a "demo".

I don't understand that behaviour at all. Where did that extra 1 minute and 15 seconds go?

And... how can I actually get the date I need, other than by resorting to `Date.parse()`?

Comment: Did you tried with `setFullYear(1)` (without UTC) and it also didn't work as expected?

Comment: @CalvinNunes: that yields `Mon Jan 01 0001 00:00:00 GMT-0001 (Greenwich Mean Time)`, which is correct *apart* from the timezone.

Comment: UTC has been adjusted since over 2000 years ago. use Calvin's suggestion. There is no timezone on the date itself, that's just output formatting, so make sure to manually adjust the input if needed. That's the main downside to using the non-locale-aware date methods.

Comment: @dandavis: See my comment - it doesn't quite work. Are you saying in effect that UTC won't work for very old dates? If so, is there a known cut-off date beyond which it doesn't work?

Comment: it does work, it just uses your timezone info, so you need to feed it what time would be happening for you locally at exactly midnight 01 in the GMT-0 zone. You can use `date.getTimezoneOffset` to calculate such an offset mechanically. I guess you could also put your computer in the GMT zone in the OS settings to get the two date formats to match, but it's better to adjust the input.

Comment: @dandavis: would you care to turn your comment into an answer? I tried, but the date I ended up with was still not correct, so obviously I'm doing it incorrectly.

Comment: `var dUTC = Date.UTC(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var date = new Date(dUTC);
date.setUTCFullYear(1);
console.log(date.toUTCString());`

Comment: Easy way to spec UTC : `new Date("0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")`. I do like @epascarello 's method too for adjusting, no more messing around with getTimezoneOffset with the newer Date.UTC...

Comment: @epascarello: That's essentially the code I have in my question, with the exception of the `toUTCString()` call. So it seems that it's the outputting of the date, rather than the date itself, that's the problem - which I think is what @dandavis was getting at. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, date is always in current timezone when you read it unless you use a UTC or GMT method when reading the vaules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post an answer since everyone prefers just to comment :-)

It turns out that the date I created was "correct", but that it was being displayed in a (erm...) "surprising" way.

So:

```
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(1, 0, 1));
console.log(date);
```

> 1901-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

```
date.setUTCFullYear(1);
console.log(date);
```

> 0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

That's what I wanted, but what I was seeing was:

```
console.log(date.toString());
```

> Sun Dec 31 0000 23:58:45 GMT-0001 (Greenwich Mean Time)

(I still think that result is weird). I would have been better to do:

```
console.log(date.toUTCString());
```

> Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT

Thanks everyone!