# continuous count up from BC date

Tags: javascript, html

*How would we modify this code to count up from a date starting in BC and continues to count up..the purpose would be to display the elapsed time from 4600BC.*
[here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ke4px1om/#&togetherjs=voixBlyid7)

```
   <div class="countup" id="countup1">
    <span class="timeel days">00</span>
    <span class="timeel timeRefDays">days</span>
    <span class="timeel hours">00</span>
    <span class="timeel timeRefHours">hours</span>
    <span class="timeel minutes">00</span>
    <span class="timeel timeRefMinutes">minutes</span>
    <span class="timeel seconds">00</span>
    <span class="timeel timeRefSeconds">seconds</span>
   </div>

    window.onload = function() {
  // Month Day, Year Hour:Minute:Second, id-of-element-container
  countUpFromTime("Jan 1, 10 12:00:00", 'countup1'); // ****** Change this line!
};
function countUpFromTime(countFrom, id) {
  countFrom = new Date(countFrom).getTime();
  var now = new Date(),
      countFrom = new Date(countFrom),
      timeDifference = (now - countFrom);
    
  var secondsInADay = 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24,
      secondsInAHour = 60 * 60 * 1000;
    
  days = Math.floor(timeDifference / (secondsInADay) * 1);
  hours = Math.floor((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) / (secondsInAHour) * 1);
  mins = Math.floor(((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);
  secs = Math.floor((((timeDifference % (secondsInADay)) % (secondsInAHour)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1);

  var idEl = document.getElementById(id);
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('days')[0].innerHTML = days;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('hours')[0].innerHTML = hours;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('minutes')[0].innerHTML = mins;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('seconds')[0].innerHTML = secs;

  clearTimeout(countUpFromTime.interval);
  countUpFromTime.interval = setTimeout(function(){ countUpFromTime(countFrom, id); }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tips for working with Pre-1000 A.D. Dates in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863327/tips-for-working-with-pre-1000-a-d-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date constructor to set the start date:

```js
const startTime = new Date(-4600, 0, 1, 12, 0);
console.log(startTime.toISOString());
```

As a general rule, it's best to avoid using the Date constructor with a string representation of the date. This doesn't work the same on all browsers.